# How to create an External Column in SharePoint 2013 designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image]

I want to create **External column**  but I **can't see the option to select the type**.

Answer (score 3):

**Create an external data column in a list or library**

```
  - Note: Creating an external data column requires Contribute permission or higher on the list or library.
```

1. Navigate to the SharePoint site, and then navigate to the list or library.

   - Note:  You cannot add an external data column to an external list.
2. Click List or Library > List Settings or Library Settings.
3. In the Columns section, click Create Column.
4. Enter the name of the column, such as Customer, and then under Column Types, click External Data.
5. Under External Content Type, click the External Content Type Picker, and then select the appropriate item from the list of external content types, for example, CustomerCRM.
6. Decide how you want to handle any actions defined for the external content type by doing one or more of the following:

   - To display a menu of one or more actions, click Display the actions
     menu.
   - To make the external data column perform the default action when
     selected, click Link this column to the Default Action of the
     external content type.
7. Under Add a column to show each of these additional fields, click Select all fields or select one or more specific field names, such as CustomerName and PhoneNumber.

([reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-update-an-external-data-column-in-a-list-or-library-44EFF2C5-8051-489D-989C-F5D09F527AEE#__toc320715147))

Comment: Is it still possible with the Sharepoint now?